# How to concatenate 3 inputs in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, date

i need to concatenate 3 inputs and  to make one value representing a date in angular typescript.

here is it my html code:

```
  <td>
                      <input type="text"  placeholder="jj" class="form-control" formControlName="jj" id="jj" name="jj" [hidden]="!chkEnable.checked" style="width:50%" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="text" placeholder="mm" class="form-control" formControlName="mm" id="mm"  name="mm" style="width: 50%"  [hidden]="!chkEnable.checked">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="text" placeholder="aa" class="form-control" formControlName="aa" id="aa" name="aa" style="width: 50%"  [hidden]="!chkEnable.checked">
                    </td>
```

My FormGroup:

```
this.dateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  jj: ['', Validators.required,Validators.max(2)],
  mm: ['', Validators.required],
  aa: ['', Validators.required]

});
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Share your `FormGroup` code

Comment: Just a thought.  Why not use a datepicker?  This seem unnecessarily tedious.

Comment: @navnath can I get ur email please ! I am stuck in angular I want to store multiples id in one column in database example (1,2,3...) Hot to do this! –

Comment: Hey, you can add your question on stackoverflow with errors you are getting.

Comment: @navnath I cant post questions here I am blocked! can you check this link https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411571/how-to-add-component-in-mat-tab-element-in-angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen for form group value changes. This will fire every time any control value changes. You can perform anything you want on this.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dateSubscription = this.dateForm.valueChanges
  .pipe(map(this.formatDate))
  .subscribe(d => console.log('MM/DD/YY', d));
}
```

Unsubscribe on destroy

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.dateSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Format Date method

```
formatDate({ aa, jj, mm }: any): string {
  return new Date(jj + '/' + +mm + '/' + +aa).toLocaleString();
}
```

To submit form

```
<form [formGroup]="dateForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

In Ts,

```
onSubmit(): void {
    // all form data
    const fromData = this.dateForm.getRawValue();
    // generate date out of it
    const date = this.formatDate(fromData);
    // create request by adding formdata with date
    const request = { ...fromData, date };
    console.log(request);
    // API call or other operation
  }
```

Pass this js date as string to laravel and in laravel convert it into Date.
Some thing like this...

```
$jsDate = '11/12/2021, 12:00:00 AM';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($jsDate));
```

// or

```
$date=date_create("12/25/2021, 12:00:00 AM");
echo date_format($date,"Y/m/d H:i:s");
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1yjzbb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: thank you! why a I getting "19** " and not "20**" Sat May 01 1920 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (UTC+01:00)

Comment: Do you want in `Date` object format or as user entred

Comment: user entered, i will insert that in my database with datetime type.

Comment: Ok. Check demo now. i have changed `.pipe(map(({ aa, jj, mm }) => jj + '/' + mm + '/' + aa)) ` You can format here as per your need

Comment: I guess with user entered i cant insert it in database with date type ! so how can I fix the 19** in  Date object ! i got this (1920-03-20 T23:00:00.000Z)

Comment: Try entering full year, month, day => like 2021...8..24. Make sure in `Date` object month and day starts with `0`. So if user entered entered 11 as month value it will be considered as 12 in Date.. as for Day.

Comment: it worked just fine !!, just another question please ! how can I use this  object in my onSubmit(); to insert it in database.

Comment: Is there any use of this Object other than inserting in database? I mean at front end? Which Prog lang u are using at backend?

Comment: Changes done for submitting date. If you just want to send a date to server, then you don't need any of the code in `Oninit, onDestroy, `

Comment: I am using laravel as  backend!  in my onSubmit I already have an obj to insert ! so I am just adding date value to that object.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please have a look. Has it solved your all problems?

Comment: Yes!! Thank you so much

Comment: can I get ur email please ! I am stuck in angular I want to store multiples id in one column in database example (1,2,3...) Hot to do this! –